# Difference between Object.create(prototype) and Object(prototype)

Tags: javascript, oop, object, prototypal-inheritance

A quick but hard-to-google question:

```
var child = Object.create(parent.prototype);

var child = Object(parent.prototype);
```

Are they identical?

---

*edit:*

My question was raised by this two examples of inheritPrototype functions used to implement the Parasitic Combination Inheritance Pattern.

```
function inheritPrototype(childObject, parentObject) {
    var copyOfParent = Object.create(parentObject.prototype);
    copyOfParent.constructor = childObject;
    childObject.prototype = copyOfParent;
}
```

http://javascriptissexy.com/oop-in-javascript-what-you-need-to-know/

```
function inheritPrototype(subType, superType){
    var prototype = object(superType.prototype); 
    prototype.constructor = subType; 
    subType.prototype = prototype;
}
```

["Parasitic Combination Inheritance" in Professional JavaScript for Web Developers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16929353/parasitic-combination-inheritance-in-professional-javascript-for-web-developer)

Comment: In Chromium `object` is undefined.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2709612/using-object-create-instead-of-new

Comment: `object` should be `Object`.

Comment: that already answered one point, thanks! the small 'object' was a quote not a typo - a quotet typo in that case, i guess ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No they are not identical see below:

1. `Object.create(prototype)` will create a new **prototype** which *inherits* from the `prototype` passed as argument
2. `Object(obj)` or `new Object(obj)` will create a new **instance** of `obj` calling the constructor as well.

Now since prototypes are javascript objects as well, the difference can be minimal. However `Object.create` can handle constructors which may need arguments, while `new Object()` will not

Further info in [this SO related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2709811/3591273) (e.g differential inheritance, custom properties and so on)

**References**:

1. [`Object.create` on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create)
2. [`new Object` on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object)

**UPDATE** after OP edit

In my OOP javascript framework [Classy.js](https://github.com/foo123/classy.js) there is this polyfill around `Object.create` for older browsers which might shed light on your further question between differences:

```
   Create = Obj.create || function( proto, properties ) {
        var Type = function () {}, TypeObject;
        Type[PROTO] = proto;
        TypeObject = new Type( );
        TypeObject[__PROTO__] = proto;
        if ( 'object' === typeOf(properties) ) defineProperties(TypeObject, properties);
        return TypeObject;
    }
```

This polyfill can handle arbitrary constructors (with arguments) like `Object.create` can, and also make sure that the `__proto__` is assigned correctly. The pattern using `Object(prototype)` in question is an attempt to (weakly-)reference the `prototype`.

Comment: @hwechselberg, it is the same as `Object(obj)` since any prototype is also an (javascript) object. `Object` will call the constructor which may have issues for constructors having arguments (or complex constructors), unlike `Object.create`. There are cother differences as well (per the referenced link)\. See also [`Object.create` on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create)

Comment: @hwechselberg, updated answer with polyfill around `Object.create` of OOP lib to see differences more clearly

Answer (score 3):

No they are not same:

> **Object(X)** or **new Object(X)** are same as **Object.create(X.prototype)**

`Object(X)` will create object and run `Constructor`( ie. the newly created object inherits from the constructor's prototype). `Object.create(X.prototype)` is creating object with additionally running `Constructor`.

> **Object(X)** or **new Object(X)** are not as **Object.create()**

`Object.create()` is creating object without running `Constructor`( ie. it will create an object that doesn't inherit from anything)

Answer (score 1):

New Object sets the child to be the parent:

```
var parent = {name : 'proto'};
var child = new Object(parent);
console.log(child === parent);//=true
//if I set child.name it will change parent.name
```

Object create returns an object instance that uses the first argument as it's proto (first prototype used in the prototype chain).

```
child = Object.create(parent);
console.log(child === parent);//=false
//I can set child.name because it will be shadowed
//  and will not change parent.name
console.log(child.hasOwnProperty('name'));//=false
```

More on prototype can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16063711/1641941

Comment: thanks. but in those examples it was Object.create(parent.**prototype**) and new Object(parent.**prototype**) - so is still don't completely see trough

Comment: @hwechselberg Sorry, didn't see that. But why would you set child.prototype to parent.prototype when you do child.prototype = new Object(parent.prototype) then child.prototype === parent.prototype You don't want that in inheritance as you want the Child.prototype to be an (empty) object with it's proto set to what you want to inherit (explained in the link in my answer) You want to lengthen the prototype chain (Child.prototype => Parent.prototype => Object.prototype) not replace Child.prototype with Parent.prototype: (Child.prototype === Patent.prototype => Object.prototype)